# Firefox CSS rendering inline style call of :not & :not

Tags: css, firefox

I have a page loading mini-widgets via Ajax, all works fine save for one small prob.
On one of the widgets, (not sure if this matters, but) the style is called in style tags just before my elements. 
FF gets through everything but completely dies one line. This works in webkit, and as far as i can see follows CSS3 standards, but FF no likey!

The line:

```
#Emails .list-row-header td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2):hover {
```

Any ideas for an alternate way to write that so i dont have to use jQuery? or a bunch of class names (this is styling dynamic elements)?

Comment: Is the missing a closing parentheses absent from your actual code or is it a typo in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses `)` on the second negation pseudo-class

Change to:

`#Emails .list-row-header td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)):hover`

(Assuming its not a typo)

Comment: Lol, you were right, but i actually found a better way using :after instead